# Using Foq Verify methodsmatch fails on interface with type parameter

Tags: f#, foq

I have an interface like this

```
type IAppDatabase = 
    abstract Get<'T> : seq<Guid> -> Task<seq<'T>>
    abstract Set<'T> : seq<'T> -> Task<bool>
    abstract GetIds<'T> : unit -> Task<seq<Guid>>
```

I try to mock like this

```
let results = seq [DT.Result (); DT.Result (); DT.Result ()]
let resultInfos = DT.Results results
let guids = seq [Guid.NewGuid(); Guid.NewGuid(); Guid.NewGuid()]

let taskGetIds = Task.Factory.StartNew<seq<Guid>>(fun () -> guids)
let taskSet = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(fun () -> true )
let taskGet = Task.Factory.StartNew<seq<DT.Result>>(fun () -> results)

let db = Mock<IAppDatabase>.With(fun x -> 
            <@  
               x.GetIds () --> taskGetIds
               x.Get guids --> taskGet
               x.Set results --> taskSet @>)
```

I have a test like this

```
let [<Test>] ``Set the resultInfos in de app database`` () =
    let app = App (db) :> IApp
    let res = app.Create resultInfos |> Async.RunSynchronously 
    verify <@db.Set results @> once
    res |> should be True
```

The `app.Create` function calls the `db.Set` with an `Async.AwaitTask`.

This all works well and Foq is great. However the verify raises an system.exception. The `methodsMatch` function in Foq returns false, because he `expectedMethod` has a `ParameterInfo.ParameterType` of ``` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[Result] ``` and the `actual.Method` has a `ParameterInfo.ParameterType` of ``` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[T] ```.

I have tried adding and removing type parameters to no avail. I need the type paramenter (and the Task) in the interface, because it is implemented by someone else in C#.

Is this an issue with the `generateAddInvocation` method or am I calling the verify wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in the current implementation of Foq 1.1 where verification against generic interface methods fails. The issue is related to the `generateAddInvocation` method which underneath uses [MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) to record each invoked method. `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` returns the generic method definition where as the code quotation used by the verify method receives the type arguments.

I have applied a simple fix: https://foq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/69435c83aabd

The fix will be part of Foq 1.2.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer and immediate action

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue :) Foq 1.2 is now available on CodePlex & via Nuget